# session status check with OIDC and ADFS 3.0

Tags: session, single-sign-on, adfs, openid-connect

I need help understanding my options for implementing a session status check. My goal is to support near real-time browser page redirection upon the termination of the session.

OIDC session management specification describes a way to check the session status with iFrames:

- http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPiframe
- I'm not using **Identity Server**, but they have a nice write-up: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout-session.html.

I see one main roadblock to doing that with ADFS though: My *.../adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration* page does not include a **check_session_iframe** endpoint. I cannot find information about the **check_session_iframe** in ADFS and what configuration controls its existence.

Can someone explain what I may be missing, or if there is another route I can investigate?

**Context:**

- ADFS 3.0 is setup for front channel logout per this recent MS article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-logout-openid-connect).
- My App uses the OWIN nuget package to connect to ADFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't feasible, so I had to change my strategy. The app just checks whether or not the app session is current, as opposed to the ADFS session.